# Is it money laundering if they want to deposit in your account?

Tags: online-banking, money-laundering

I would like to know if somebody asks for your banking account number and routing number but they are just depositing money into your account but is that money laundering?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without knowing where the money came from. Be advised that many many scams start this way. Browse the scams tag on this site and see if any of it sounds familiar.

Comment: Question #1: **WHY** is this person "*just* depositing money into your account"?  Because random strangers, and "best friends you just met on the Internet" just don't do that without having an **ULTERIOR MOTIVE**.

Comment: (There is no Question #2.)

Comment: Who is "they"?  Could be perfectly legitimate: many companies pay their employees by direct depost; when I sell some of my mutual funds, the money gets deposited in the bank; I pay my horse boarding by direct deposit to their account...  Now IF they want to know account & routing number so they can give you money for no good reason, THEN it's a scam of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if somebody asks for your banking account number
> and routing number but they are just depositing money into your
> account but is that money laundering?

It isn't money laundering, but....

If they then want you to take the money out and send it somewhere, then it could be money laundering.

If they want to pull the money out, and send it to somebody, and then they reverse their transfer it was because they want to steal from you.

If they transferred the money from another victims account, and want you to send the money someplace else before the bank/police  catches on, it could be theft or money laundering, or both.

Never give this information to a stranger. Only give it to somebody you owe money to (it is written on each of your checks). They don't need this information to send money to you, though they will probably see it after you cash their check.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely. With that information they can also withdraw money from your account. So they are probably just trying to steal your money.

Never give out that information except for someone you TRUST and want to authorize to withdraw money from your account, for example a payment.

If they want to deposit money, just have them send you a check or something. Much safer.

Comment: “With that information they can also withdraw money from your account.”  Does that depend on the location?  Here in the UK I'm not aware that a random person can withdraw money given a bank account and sort code, without any sort of authorisation.